# overloading operator !=

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, smart-pointers

I wrote a smarter pointer class. And to make the following code correct

```
ZhjSmartPointer<int> a(new int);  
assert(a != NULL);
```

I overload the != operator like this:

```
bool operator !=(T *ptr) const;
```

however, this leads to a compile error like this:

> ZhjSmartPointer.h:132: note: candidate 1: bool
>   ZhjSmartPointer::operator!=(T*) const [with T = Test] test.cpp:41:
>   note: candidate 2: operator!=(int, int)

I'm confuse with how a `ZhjSmartPointer` can be transfered into an `int`

The Code of SmartPointer class is like this:

```
template <typename T>
class ZhjSmartPointer {
public:
    ZhjSmartPointer();
    explicit ZhjSmartPointer(T *ptr);

    ZhjSmartPointer(const ZhjSmartPointer &smartPtr);
    ZhjSmartPointer &operator =(const ZhjSmartPointer &smartPtr);
    ~ZhjSmartPointer();

    operator bool() const;
    T &operator *() const;
    T *operator ->() const;
    bool operator ==(const ZhjSmartPointer &smartPtr) const;
    bool operator !=(const ZhjSmartPointer &smartPtr) const;

    bool operator ==(T *ptr) const;
    bool operator !=(T *ptr) const;

private:
    void copyPtr(const ZhjSmartPointer &smartPtr);
    void deletePtr();
    T *ptr_;
    size_t *refCnt_;
};
```

I guess because I overload the 'bool' operator, 'ZhjSmartPointer -> bool -> int' leads to this problem.Is this right?

Sorry,It is just a compile warning, not a error. Someone suggest me not overloading != with parameter(T *), after all, we already have overloaded 'bool'.It will be fine to write codes like these:
    ZhjSmartPointer a(new int);
    if (a) {
    ..........
    }

Comment: a constructor taking in a `int` as parameter without `explicit` could cause that conversion.

Comment: The constructor wouldn't take an `int` (well T), but a `int*` (T*), so the "implicit constructor conversion" exists doesn't make much sense. What does make sense is the assumption that you allow an implicit conversion from `ZhjSmartPointer<int>` to `int` which would then lead to this error. Really not much you can do, apart from using `intptr` or removing the implicit conversion.

Comment: As I said in my answer below, it works for me on `g++ 4.6.3` with a warning issued. So I guess it is compiler-dependent. What's your compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I guess because I overload the 'bool' operator, 'ZhjSmartPointer -> bool -> int' leads to this problem.Is this right?

I think so.

But *have you defined any conversion operator for* `ZhjSmartPointer`?

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>

template <class T>
class ZhjSmartPointer{
    public:
    ZhjSmartPointer (T* _ptr)
    :ptr_saved(_ptr){    }
    bool operator !=(T *ptr) const{
        return ptr!=ptr_saved;
    }
    private:
    T* ptr_saved;
};
int main(){
    ZhjSmartPointer<int> a(new int);  
    assert(a != NULL);     
}
```

This compiles for me though (`g++ 4.6.3`).
adding:

```
    operator bool() const{
        return ptr_saved!=0;
    }
```

`g++ 4.6.3` issues a **warning**, but still it compiles.

```
1.cpp:9:14： Candidate 1： bool ZhjSmartPointer<T>::operator!=(T*) const [with T = int]
1.cpp:20:9： Candidate 2： operator!=(int, int) <builtin>
```

---

**DEPRECATED**

*Surprisingly* `NULL` is an `int`, not a `void*`.

Declaring your constructor like:

```
ZhjSmartPointer<int> a(new int);
```

enables the conversion from int to `ZhjSmartPointer`. Instead, add an `explicit`:

```
explicit ZhjSmartPointer<int> a(new int);
```

to suppress this conversion.

Comment: How is the former (or the latter) a constructor *declaration* ? All I see is a *variable* declaration. In fact, *explicit* can only appear on non-static member functions; the snippet above won't even compile.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ `NULL` is defined as `0`, not `(void*)0`, in fact most textbooks will tell you to use `0` instead of `NULL`.

If you're using C++11 you should be using `nullptr` by the way

---

Your problem is indeed the `bool` implicit conversion. To fix your problem overload operator not (`!`) instead.

Comment: In C++11 there's `nullptr` which is a different type to `0`; `NULL` and `0` are semantically different and it's bad practice to depend on the fact that they equate, so "most textbooks" contain bad advice.

Comment: @CongXu Nope, `NULL` and `0` are *exactly* the same thing semantically in C++. Relying on this fact is perfectly fine (you may say "But what if the hardware represents null pointers differently?" In which case I'd say: "The standard says the compiler has to take care to convert this correctly"). Not that I like this fact - `nullptr` is nice.

Comment: @Voo By "semantically" I meant with respect to the programmer, i.e. you should be using `NULL` for pointers and `0` for numbers, even though they are guaranteed to be equal. With respect to the language it's the other way around; sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @CongXu Ah yes there we agree. Some people seem to prefer 0 to NULL though - Bjarne Stroustroup being the most famous example I can think of (his explanation is "I prefer to avoid macros") - to each their own, I prefer NULL (although having an explicit 0 makes problems with overload resolution clearer), respectively nullptr in c++11

Comment: @CongXu You are incorrect, in the beginnings of C++ `NULL` was actually *not* `0` but still `(void*)0`, which is not allowed to be implicitly cast to a pointer of any type T other than `void` which means that `ptr == NULL` is fine as `ptr` will be converted implicitly to `void*`, but `T* ptr = NULL` is not fine. In C++ it was expressly the intention to use `0` and not `NULL`. However since unbending programmers still wanted to use `NULL`, `NULL` was changed in C++ to be `0` instead. In C++11 we now have `nullptr` to solve the issue.